# How to use to_tsquery (postgres) in PDO?

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo, full-text-search

I try to use full text search like

```
$STM = $PDO->prepare('SELECT title FROM zz_ad.advs WHERE to_tsvector(title) @@ to_tsquery(:str)');
$STM->execute(['str' => 'Hi!']);
$STM->fetchAll();
```

As a result i have: **ERROR: syntax error in tsquery: "Hi!"**

If i try without a "!" its work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For [the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-textsearch.html#DATATYPE-TSQUERY):

> A tsquery value stores lexemes that are to be searched for, and combines them honoring the Boolean operators & (AND), | (OR), and ! (NOT). Parentheses can be used to enforce grouping of the operators.

'Hi!' is not a valid lexeme. 'Hi' is.